# what is "--" mean in C# and what about in F#

Tags: c#, f#

in C# there is code like this

```
int someVariable=10;
--someVariable; //what is the meaning?
```

what about in F#? can i do like in C# code?

Comment: in C# it means `someVar = someVar - 1;`

Comment: That certainly doesn't *look* like C# code, with the double `;;`. Although it is valid C#, it's very unusual to do it.

Comment: It is a mutability feature. Please don't expect one by one translation from C# to F#.

Comment: @pad:just try to learn F#, make some case and then try to make it using F# :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--` operator BEFORE a variable decrements the value by one before returning the value.  AFTER a variable, it gets the value and then decrements.  So

```
 int i = 2;
 ((--i) == 2) # false
```

and the value of `i` is 1 after.

```
 int i = 2;
 ((i--) == 2) # true
```

and the value of `i` is still 1 after.

I don't think F# has it.

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing as **someVariable = someVariable - 1**.

The result would be 10 - 1, or 9.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained `--` operator in C#. Because F# is a functional programming language which advocates immutability by default, there's no built-in operator which does the same thing. You have to write it explicitly using `mutable` values:

```
let mutable someVariable = 10
someVariable <- someVariable - 1
```

Since users are aware of mutability using `mutable` keywords, they can avoid some mistakes like those caused by hidden side effects of prefix and postfix `--` operators in C#.

As @Daniel said in the comment, you could also use a [reference cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx) and [decr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353797.aspx) function for the same purpose.

Comment: is it same with --someVariable? from what mr.Charlie told, --someVariable isn't assign the result into the value when (called?) ( sorry , i don't know the right term)

Comment: You could also use a [`ref` cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx) and [`decr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353797.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the meaning of --someVariable is:

```
(someVariable=someVariable-1;return someVariable)
```

as opposed to someVariable--, which means:

```
(return someVariable; someVariable=someVariable-1)
```

( which is not valid as it stands, but gives you the idea );

There are equivalent prefix and postfix ++ operators. In reality, the postfix ++ operator is the most commonly used by a long way, although it is important to know about the others.

The double semi-colons at the end are wrong, but not invalid. It looks like someone has copied form somewhere else, or is used to writing in a different language.

Comment: yes, my bad, since i learn using F# and use the C# at the same time, sometime i make mistake when i write the semi-colons